# Synchronize between CardDav and LDAP

Tags: ldap, telephony

Is there is an application/service which synchronize contacts from CardDav to LDAP?

My plan is to synchronize the contacts which are used in ownCloud to my PBX so I have it on my desktop phone which is linked to the PBX via ISDN.